# Why $ M\models \forall x ( \alpha \to \beta)$ Is False?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

if M be a model and $\alpha$ and $ \beta$ be two formula the following is False:

> $ M \models \forall x ( \alpha \to \beta)$ if and only if $ M \models \forall x \alpha$ has conclusion $ M \models \forall x \beta $

My question is why this is a false statement !?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\forall x\alpha$, not $\forall x>\alpha$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is it okey now.

Comment: You can re-write the right hand side as $M \models (\forall x \alpha) \rightarrow (\forall x \beta)$. Then you want $M\models \forall x (\neg \alpha \lor \beta)$ iff $M\models (\neg \forall x( \alpha)) \lor \forall x (\beta)$. It may be easier to reason about this form.

Comment: again it's not well understood by me !? @James

Comment: $\phi \rightarrow \psi$ is equivalent to $\neg \phi \lor \psi$.

Comment: @James would you please make it clearer? It say as a corollary in my note.

Comment: It's very hard for us to help you, as you don't explain what you don't understand. Have you tried constructing a counter-example? If you can't, have you tried proving it, and observing where you get stuck? Have you noticed that the "only if" direction (i.e. $\Rightarrow$) is true? Can you prove this fact?

Comment: @James is there anyway to show it's not true except counterexample ?

Answer (score 2):

Take the model $\mathfrak A\,$ whose domain is $\{a,b \}$, and let $\alpha:=F(x)$ and $\beta:=G(x)$, and finally let $F=\{a \}$ and $G=\{b \}$.

Recall that for finite domains $(\forall x)\varphi$ is equivalent to the conjunction $\varphi a_1 \land \varphi a_2 \,...\land \,\varphi a_n \; $ for an $n$ sized domain.

I'll show that $\mathfrak A\,$ is a countermodel to the following statement: 
$$(1)\;\;\;\;\; For\;all\;models\;M  \;\;\;\;\; M\vDash \forall x(\alpha \to  \beta) \;\;iff\;\; M\vDash \forall x(\alpha) \Rightarrow \;M\vDash \forall x(\alpha)$$
$(1)$ fails from right to left.

For suppose  $\mathfrak A\vDash (Fa\land Fb)\Rightarrow \mathfrak A\vDash(Ga\land Gb)\, $, which is **true** vacuously, since the antecedent is false. That is, $b\notin F$, so $(Fa\land Fb)$ is false, which makes $\mathfrak A\vDash (Fa\land Fb)$ false.

But $\mathfrak A\vDash (Fa\to Ga)\land (Fa\to Ga)\,$ is **false**, since in the first conjunct the antecedent is true, but the consequent is false. That is, $a\in F$ but $a\notin G$, so the conditional $Fa\to Ga\,$ is false, which makes the conjunction $(Fa\to Ga)\land (Fa\to Ga)\,$ false.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to verbalise as follows:

Left hand side: for every $x\in M$, if $\alpha(x)$ is true then so is $\beta(x)$.
On the right hand side: if ($\forall x \in M \alpha(x)$) then ($\forall x \in M \beta(x)$)

Then, it should be clear that we can make a following counterexample:
$\alpha(0)$ is false, $\alpha(1)$ is true, $\beta(0)$ and $\beta(1)$ are both true. Then $\alpha(0)\rightarrow \beta(0)$ is false, so the left hand side is false, but the right hand side is true.
Hope this is helpful!

Comment: If $\alpha(0)=$**f** and $\beta(0)=$**t**, then $α(0) \to β(0)=$**t**.